# Dynamically created div is draggable but not droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

on the left sidebar, i have (hard-coded) a "Report Sections" list of dragable objects (li's - div's) and a list of "Widgets" (also li's - div's) that are dynamically generated from some database records

i dynamically create a number of rows (div's) by dragging from the reports section elements and dropping (cloning) them into the container.

[image]

the list of the widgets starts with a hard-coded element (called "Alerts") and then continues with the dynamically created ones (DISSATISFACTION DRIVERS*, etc...)

when i drag the first (hard coded) widget, "Alerts," into a Row, the dropping works fine and the result looks like this

[image]

when i try to drop any other (dynamically created) widget from the list, the dragging works but the dropping doesn't work. I am at loss! If the dragging works on the widgets, then the problem should be with the droppable container, not accepting the widgets. If it is so, then why would the droppable functionality work in the container for the hard coded "Alerts" widget (same div class, same everything) and not for the dynamically created ones? Inspecting the page elements, specifically the widget list, all the entries look the same (except for the description.)

the code for the hard coded "Alerts:"

```
<div class="box box-element ui-draggable">      
    <a class="remove label label-danger" href="#close">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> remove</a>
    <span class="drag label label-default ui-draggable-handle">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
    <div class="preview">Alerts</div>
    <div class="view">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <h4>Alert!</h4>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

the code for the first dynamically created widget (the rest of the widgets are the same)

```
<div class="box box-element ui-draggable">
    <a class="remove label label-danger" href="#close">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> remove</a>
    <span class="drag label label-default ui-draggable-handle">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-move"></i> drag</span>
    <div class="preview">DISSATISFACTION DRIVERS*</div>
    <div class="view">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
            <strong>Widget!</strong> Widget Name.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

any ideas?